# regex - ignore escaped chars within quotation marks

Tags: php, regex, nested, escaping, regex-lookarounds

I am working with regular expressions for years now but this time I am struggling hard.

Assuming I have the following simple string.

```
$content = "foo 'bar \' [\'],' test";
```

Now I want to match everything within single quotation marks. There are even escaped characters in it. With my current regex those escaped characters are blowing up the results.

```
$regex = "/\'[^\'\\\\]*(?:\\\\.[^\'\\\\]*)*\'/";
```

The results

```
// expected
[0] => "'bar \' [\'],'"

// current
[0] => "'],'"
```

Live demo [HERE](https://regex101.com/r/zX5ciw/2).

Comment: It worked for me with `(?<!\\)'.*?(?<!\\)'`

Comment: Your `$content = "foo 'bar \' [\'],' test"` has no ``\`` chars in it. Test against `$content = "foo 'bar \\' [\\'],' test"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want here to find an open quote and its closing one, so no escaped quote.
`(?<!\\)'.*?(?<!\\)'` will do so
Explanation :

`(?<!` negative lookbehind
`\\)` escaped backslash and closing lookbehind
`'` the quote which has not been escaped (the negative look behind has checked it)
`.*?` any char : `.*` in lazy mode : `?` so the next quote will be evaluate
`(?<!\\)` again negative lookbehind to check if the quote has been escaped
`'` Final not escaped quote

Answer (score 1):

You can try  like this one

```
'([^']|(\'))*'
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zX5ciw/3)

Or even more precise

```
'([^']|(\'))*?(?<!\\)'
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zX5ciw/5)